# Trying to programmatically add a button to UINavigationController but it never shows up

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

I've programmatically created some UINavigationControllers and added them to a UITabBarController.  Everything seems to work fine but I wanted to add a cancel button to the navigation controller but it never shows up.  I've tried multiple ways but I can't seem to affect the display of the navigation items at all and I've followed multiple examples from here and other sites but nothing happens.

```
MyTableViewController *mtvc = [[MyTableViewController alloc] init]; 
UINavigationController *myNavController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mtvc] autorelease];
myNavController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;  // this works
[mtvc release];

// TODO: figure out why added buttons aren't showing
UIBarButtonItem *closeButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(shutDown)] autorelease]; 
myNavController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = closeButton;  // never shows up
```

I also tried adding the button this way

```
[myNavController.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:closeButton animated:NO];  // also doesn't do anything
```

I started getting frustrated so I also tried some other things just to see if I could affect anything, but to no avail

```
myNavController.title = @"test";  // does nothing
```

I've tried doing it before and after the navigations controllers were added to the UITabBarController and that didn't help.
I've also tried rightBarButtonItem and tried using initWithTitle: instead of initWithBarButtonSystemItem.

Would someone please illuminate me?  Clearly, I'm doing this the wrong way.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try adding the bar buttons in the `loadView` method of `MyTableViewController` like the follwing.

```
UIBarButtonItem *closeButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(shutDown)] autorelease]; 
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = closeButton;
```

I guess that should work.

Comment: That did it @Simon . Thanks!  I had a feeling I needed to do this from inside the appropriate view controller.  I had tried to do this before in the `init` method which makes sense that it wouldn't work.  Doing it inside the `loadView` method worked like a champ.

Comment: Note: It didn't like my using `autorelease` followed by an explicit `release`.  Should probably be one or the other.

Comment: @digarok: Yeah.. Sorry.. That's my mistake.. I didn't notice the autorelease there..

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried setting the button of the current view controller's navigation item like this:

```
mtvc.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = closeButton;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to do that in Swift 3.0, it is simple like that:

```
let closeButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.cancel,
                        target: self,
                        action: #selector({Your-viewController}.{close-method}))
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = closeButton
```